# How to show last column of chart series in report viewer?

Tags: c#, reporting, report-viewer2010

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ6eD.png)

Hi friends here I just want to show last column of a chart series as like other column .How can I make it ,if you know please answer for this